# Break out of while loop after 5 seconds in Swift

Tags: swift, loops, time, break, seconds

I want to timeout and break out of this loop in 5 seconds. Only thing I could find online is having a count variable increment every second and then breaking if the count is 5, but was wondering if there's an easier, less codier way. Please help!

```
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
while (locationManager.location == nil) {
    //searching...
}
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: You could measure the current time before entering the loop, and again each time you run the loop. Compare the actual value to the one you got at the beginning, and if the difference is bigger than 5 seconds, `break`. This is just  a straight answer to what you asked for. However, @AlBlue's answer below is what you should do on iOS.

Comment: ...or any other system where blocking the main thread means blocking the graphical user interface.

Comment: There is nothing like "less codier". The most important metric is "correct" and "more readable". Infinite cycles done in this way are wrong in the first place. A time limit won't improve them.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with having a while loop is that it will block the user's use of the application if it's on the main thread. Instead of doing that, you should start updating the location and then schedule a background thread using GCD (assuming you're on OSX; GCD isn't available on Linux yet) to run in a five seconds to disable the location manager. You could also schedule it to run in one second, check to see if it's present and then either attempt again or just let it run for five seconds.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a delay function like this:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {

        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)


    }
```

and after use it like this:

```
 delay(5){
locationManager.location = //something different from nil or you can try with break sentence ; not sure if with break will work though .

    }
```